# Play mp3 file on shake gesture

Tags: android

I've searched for hours and can't figure out how to play an MP3 file on a shake gesture. I'm new to android, and i know how to use MediaPlayer to play an mp3 file once a button is pressed but i want to incorporate a shake gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SensorEventListener` will resolve your purpose. Go through [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/android-shake-to-refresh-tutorial.html) for reference.

```
@Override 
public void onShake() {
    // This is where you need to play your mp3 file 
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I tried copy and pasting the apprortiate code from the link to ShakeEventManager.java and MainActivity.java, but I'm getting errors in the ShakeEventManager.java file